# Excel VBA UDF Count Ifs with data conversion

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am attempting to write a UDF using Countifs. I want the user to be able to select criteria 1 (held as X1) and the month (held as month_X). The month in the lookup table is in numbers so I want the function to convert the month name to the month number.

This works - but is there a better way to convert the data? I.e. less lines of code?

```
Function CountIF_Custom(X1 As String, Month_X As String)
    Dim MonthArray(1 To 12, 1 To 2) As Variant

    MonthArray(1, 1) = "January"
    MonthArray(2, 1) = "February"
    MonthArray(3, 1) = "March"
    MonthArray(4, 1) = "Apr"
    MonthArray(5, 1) = "May"
    MonthArray(6, 1) = "June"
    MonthArray(7, 1) = "July"
    MonthArray(8, 1) = "August"
    MonthArray(9, 1) = "September"
    MonthArray(10, 1) = "October"
    MonthArray(11, 1) = "November"
    MonthArray(12, 1) = "December"

    MonthArray(1, 2) = "1"
    MonthArray(2, 2) = "2"
    MonthArray(3, 2) = "3"
    MonthArray(4, 2) = "4"
    MonthArray(5, 2) = "5"
    MonthArray(6, 2) = "6"
    MonthArray(7, 2) = "7"
    MonthArray(8, 2) = "8"
    MonthArray(9, 2) = "9"
    MonthArray(10, 2) = "10"
    MonthArray(11, 2) = "11"
    MonthArray(12, 2) = "12"

    For x = 1 To 12
        If Month_X = MonthArray(x, 1) Then
            Month_X = MonthArray(x, 2)
        End If
    Next x

    CountIF_Custom = Application.CountIfs(Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("SomeRange"), X1, Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("SomeRange"), Month_X)

    End Function
```

Comment: You could put your months in a regular array and use Appication.Match to convert month name to a number.

Comment: just use `=MONTH(1&A1)`

Comment: Dammit @Rosetta - was commenting on your deleted answer. :)  Was trying to say - you need a space in that `Month`.  `month(1 & "December")` returns a `type mismatch` while `month(1 & " December")` returns 12.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, sorry i caused the sufferings :p. i didn't answer the question in vba / udf wanted by OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the array, you can use a for loop with the MonthName function:

```
Function CountIF_Custom(X1 As String, Month_X As String)

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 12
    If Month_X = MonthName(x) Then
        Month_X = CStr(x)
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

CountIF_Custom = Application.CountIfs(Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("SomeRange"), X1, Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("SomeRange"), Month_X)

End Function
```

Comment: don't even need to loop: `Month_X=cstr(month(datevalue("01 "+Month_X+" 2017")))`

Comment: @SeanC Can even leave the year off `CStr(Month(DateValue("01 " & Month_X)))` (I always use `&` to avoid accidentally summing numbers - not relevant in this case, but still....)